# problem with javascript, simple recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursive-query

I am really not very familiar with javascript and its syntax, but I have worked out this function,, and I keep getting errors when I call it recursively.

```
function loading(id, formid, point)
{
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<span class="red">Please wait until this text disappears! Uploading'+point+'</span>';
    document.getElementById(formid).submit();
        if(point='...')
            {point='';}
        else
            {point+='.';}
        setTimeout('loading('+id+', '+formid+', '+point+')',10);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null
```

So it seems like the variable formid is not passed to the recursiv call. Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Maenny

Comment: change `if(point='...')` to `if(point=='...')`.  
"=" means assignation (you are giving the value "..." to the variable point) and you need to verify an equality using "=="

Comment: Doh! I could have seen that for myself... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you eval `formid` into the function again, you aren't surrounding it with quotes, so you are passing a undefined variable instead of a string.

eval is evil anyway. Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass functions.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    loading(id, formid, point);
},10);
```

Comment: ok thanks, that worked concerning the recursiv call, but did actually not what I wanted :) I want a text to appear during an upload where the last 3 points (uploading ...) will appear counting up to '...' and disappear again, starting over. I thought the above function would do that, but it doesn't. Any ideas why?